# Constantly forcing reload of a page on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, mobile

I have a Wordpress site running a plugin called OpenHours. Basically, we program in our operating hours to the backend of the site and then have a page `/hours/` which shows them. I have disabled every possible Caching feature in Wordpress and tried editing the `.htaccess` file with the below:

```
# DISABLE CACHING
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(css|flv|gif|htm|html|ico|jpe|jpeg|jpg|js|mp3|mp4|png|pdf|swf|txt)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        FileETag None
        Header unset ETag
        Header unset Pragma
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Expires "Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

We have a mobile app that basically links users to the webpage through their phone's browser, but anytime the link is clicked the page doesn't update (The plugin is configured to show "Currently Open" or "Currently Closed" based on time of day). Is there a way to force the page to update and not cache whenever it is visited?

I tried a query string but unfortunately the spot we insert the link in the app does not support any type of coding, just a straight link, so `/hours/?rnd="+Math.random()` and `/hours/?rnd="+new Date().getTime()` haven't worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can set new headers for a specific page using the default PHP **header** function.

```
add_action("init", function() {
    // TODO: Replace with the actual page ID or title
    if(!is_page("page-without-cache")) return;

    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
    header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies.
}, 10);
```

We used the **init** function to make sure that the header is sent before rendering the page.

And if you are using any cache plugin, you should be able to create a list of URLs or directories that you do not want to include or that you do not want to be cached. For example, in the WP Super Cache plugin, the option is located in the **Advanced tab > Accepted Filenames & Rejected URIs** section. By default, these paths are excluded from cache.

```
wp-.*\.php
index\.php
```

And in addition, WP have dedicated functions called **nocache_headers** or **wp_nocache_headers**, which you can also use to prevent caching. The functions are also using the default PHP header function.